# Managing employees' attendance using Face Recognition

Tags: pi-3, pi-2, camera, opencv

I'm creating an employees' attendance management system using Face recognition on RPi (2 or 3). I use Python `face_recognition` library for face detecting and recognition. I currently think of two ways to create the system:

1. Using `face_recognition` and `flask` to make a web service and then, create a client using web technology with `electron` or `nwjs`, show the camera stream using WebRTC and communicate with that service.
2. Using `OpenCV` to show the camera stream and then if an employee shows their face in front of the camera for about 10 sec, it will automatically check their attendance.

Actually, I kind of prefer method 2. But I wonder if running and showing an infinite camera stream on RPi using OpenCV could affect the performance?

Have any ideas ? Thank you in advance!

Comment: gazing for 10 sec onto cam can't be good solution ( human eng wise ).